# How do I get a big \sumint symbol?

Tags: math-mode, xetex, symbols, unicode-math

I am using Cambria Math as math font with unicode-math.

When I typeset `\sumint` in a Document using  it appears much smaller than `\int`. How can I instruct unicode-math to select a bigger variant of the `\sumint` glyph?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}%

These two symbols don't have the same height:
\[
\sum\limits^b_a \sumint\limits^b_a
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to include an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so we can see in more detail what the problem is.

Comment: Yes you are right, I added a small example that runs fine with XeLaTeX showing the size difference.

Comment: Can you please add an image of the output? Not everybody has Cambria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REVISED SOLUTION**

Here, I superimpose the necessary glphys from Cambria Math to achieve the goal, using `\DeclareMathOperator*` to lock it in place:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Sumint}{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\displaystyle\sum}{%
  \stackanchor[0pt]{\symbol{"2320}}{\symbol{"2321}}}}}
\begin{document}%
\[
\symbol{"2320}\symbol{"2321}\sum
\]
\[
\int_0^x \sum_0^x \Sumint_0^x
\quad
\sumint_0^x \textstyle\sumint_0^x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one wanted the symbol to be a bit more vertically compact, one could change the stacking gap of the integral stems from `[0pt]` as shown in the MWE above to as much as `[-2pt]` without a noticeable mismatch.  Here is that comparison:

[image]

**ORIGINAL SOULTION**

It is not an ideal solution because scaling the glyph changes the glyph's stroke weight, but the `scalerel` package allows the smaller `\sumint` to take on the same vertical footprint, in this case, as `\displaystyle\int`.

The last two cases show the essence of the problem...that `\textstyle` and `\displaystyle` versions of `\sumint` produce identical (text style) output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
        \setmainfont{Cambria}
    \usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
        \setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\begin{document}%

\[
\int_0^x \sum_0^x \mathop{\scalerel*{\sumint}{\displaystyle\int}}\limits_0^x 
\quad
\sumint_0^x \textstyle\sumint_0^x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed work as you describe. However I don't think this is satisfactory as FontForge shows that a bigger version of the `\sumint` glyph is provided by Cambria Math. Sadly it doesn't seem to be possible to instruct unicode-math to use that glyph...

Comment: @LifeIsHealthy What unicode slot do you think the big symbol is in?  I found the smaller size in slot `"2A0B`, but found no comparable larger symbol.

Comment: @LifeIsHealthy Please see revised approach.

Comment: Thank you very much the new output does look a lot better I think. This still seems like a hack but one I can live with. The stackengine package seems useful. I accepted your answer as it seems the only way to go with this problem.